# How do I extend Apache Solr's ExtractingRequestHandler to extract content from Protocol Buffer files?

Tags: solr

I've setup an instance of SolrCloud. Now I want to index the content in files which are in protocol buffer format and also store them in Solr using `stored=true` attribute. Storing binary document is easy. Now how do I go ahead in instructing solr to extract content from protocol buffer files?
I know we can extend ExtractingRequestHandler to do the same but I was unable to find comprehensive documentation on doing the same on the wiki page here : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending the ExtractingRequestHandler I would go with SolrJ. In that way you can do whatever you want, your client will run in a separate JVM, it will extract content(using your favourite library) and finally it will connect to Solr. Something like this:

```
// Extract content from PB files
String content = extractContentFromPBFiles();

// The facade towards Solr
SolrClient client = ...

// The Input value object (i.e. a Solr Document that needs to be indexed)
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.setField("id", <your id>);
doc.setField("content", content);

// Add
client.add(doc);

// Commit (you may want to avoid this in case of massive inserts)
client.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I'm extracting content already but I don't know how to store the original document (That is store my original PB file as binary blob in Solr). Any clues?

Comment: In the example schema there's a binary field which (I never used that) I guess it encodes the binary content using base64. Are you sure you really need to index binary content? Usually people retain that data outside Solr, retrieving at query time the required content for each match result

Comment: I'm using `index=false` and `stored=true` for binary content because I have really large no of files: more than 5 million and I felt solr can store them better (as it compresses and also stores content in other files than index) than a file system.

Comment: Mmmm "better than a filesystem"? Are you sure? Stored fields are copied verbatim and if my guess is right, base64 is not so efficient in terms of disk space

Comment: I used to think filesystem is better than Solr for storing binary content but a chat on IRC was convincing enough to change my intuition. Unfortunately, I don't have much details now.  The argument was filesystem needs to do a search for each level in hierarchy but Solr doesn't need to. (I've forgotten the inner details but Solr is efficient than a file system).